# How to achieve data locality with polymorphism?

Tags: c++, caching, polymorphism

(The title might be "not so optimal".)

Suppose there's code like this:

```
class Foo {/*stuff*/};
class Bar1 : Foo {/*stuff*/};
class Bar2 : Foo {/*stuff*/};

std::vector<Foo*> foos;

// Populate 'foos' with Foo, Bar1 and Bar2 objects

// Iterate through foos
for(Foo* foo : foos) foo->doSomething();
```

Basically, `foos` is a vector with `Foo` object pointers. However, looping through this vector is likely to cause cache misses. A theoretical remedy would be to store actual objects instead of pointers, but this isn't allowed in C++ (no polymorphism with arrays).

That said: How can one improve data locality (and minimize cache misses) when lots of polymorphic objects are required?

I'm interested about this since everyone tells me that cache hits / misses are of great importance in performance-critical software, and thus one should avoid the use of pointers like in the code sample given above. However, this would essentially mean throwing away polymorphism.

Comment: Is `doSomething` a `virtual` function that is likely overridden? If not it might be sitting (and remain) in the icache early on.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier For the sake of this hypothetical question, yes, it is a virtual function that may or may not be overridden. However, I'm more interested to know about the iteration than what is actually done with the objects.

Comment: You could use a memory pool to allocate your objects in a contiguous memory location, it doesn't remove the indirection but your objects are most likely to be on the same cache line which depending on your hardware might improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will often be the case that you have to sacrifice performance in order to use polymorphism but in this case perhaps you can maintain separate vectors of `Bar1` and `Bar2`. You could consider these a "pool" of `Bar1` and `Bar2`.

And then fill the vector of `Foo` object pointers with pointers to objects in your `Bar1` and `Bar2` pools:

```
template<typename Bar>
void populateFoos(std::vector<Foo*>& foos, std::vector<Bar>& bars) {
    for (auto& bar : bars)
        foos.emplace_back(&bar);
}

std::vector<Bar1> bar1s;
std::vector<Bar2> bar2s;

std::vector<Foo*> foos;

// Populate Bar1s
bar1s.emplace_back();
bar1s.emplace_back();

// Populate Bar2s
bar2s.emplace_back();

// Populate 'foos' with Bar1 and Bar2 objects
populateFoos(foos, bar1s);
populateFoos(foos, bar2s);

// Iterate through foos
for(auto foo : foos) 
    foo->doSomething();
```

<kbd>[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/XFhErM2rAALodlXW)</kbd>

You will need to be careful that you don't invalidate the `Foo` object pointers by reallocating your `Bar1` and `Bar2` pools.